# How to retrieve an id from the HashMap

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, ui-automation

I have the below script where I get the id correctly but when I append it to the url I am getting as

**java null pointer Exception.**

Below is the method I used to store the ids:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> createdValue; 
    
public static void getid(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException      
{
    String pendingconfirm = buttonXpath_Replace.replace("XXXX", "Pending confirm"); 
    clickOnButton(driver, pendingconfirm);          
    createdValue = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<WebElement> tableValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span"));
    int tableValueSize = tableValues.size();
    System.out.println("Get the no of rows:"+tableValueSize);
    WebElement latestId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span)["+tableValueSize +"]"));
    System.out.println("Latest DemandIds: "+ latestId .getText());
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span)["+tableValueSize +"]")));
    createdValue.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()); 
    System.out.println(createdValue.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()));     
}
```

Then I call the above method in order to append the `latestId` to the url:

```
String confirmationURL = "https://test-webapp.net/#/type=confirm";
List<String> newurls = new ArrayList<String>();
newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + createdValue.get("latestDataId"));
```

so in this case I fetch the id from the previous method by appending as above but when I do this it is not fetching the id and causes a null pointer Exception.

Any inputs on what I can do to get this resolved.

Comment: Please format you question. Check [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Is it really intentional that you always create a new `HashMap` in your `getid` method? I suspect that you should initialize your static hash map right where you declare it. It has to be initialized before you invoke any other methods on it.

Comment: just run that method and see what is the out of this line `System.out.println(createdValue.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()));  ` ?

Comment: thanks for the response but can you give more inputs

Comment: yes i ran that and it did fetch the latest id

Comment: the problem is when iam calling  it in this place -newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + createdValue.get("latestDataId"));

Comment: this is the place where i get the null pointer it is basically not fetching the id

Comment: @Hulk  can i get more inputs

Comment: in this line, the only thing that can lead to a `NullPointerException` is the map itself - `createdValue` - being `null`. So you probably get there before you initialized it. You have not shown us where you invoke `getid()`, so I cannot be sure. Just step through your code with a debugger, or add some debug outputs to see what is happening.

Comment: ok so you are saying that before i call - newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + createdValue.get("latestDataId"));  ---- i need to getID(Driver);

Comment: yes, because that is where you create the map. But actually, you should probably create the map somewhere else, e.g. statically when declaring `createdValue`.

Comment: yes i added the line and it is working now thanks hulk for the help

Comment: is there anywhere i can upvote

Comment: @hulk i tried to give as you said but when i run the entire script it causes stale element it is bz the method has lastetid.click and also createdValue.get("latestDataId"));  i would need both of these lines bz in one screen iam clicking the id and in another screen iam appending the id to the url  can i get a input on what i need to do to have both in one method and use the same method in all the places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically `createdValue` and `getid` both are static, so when you are calling it like this :

```
newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + createdValue.get("latestDataId"));
```

this is getting called :

```
public static HashMap<String, String> createdValue;
```

and since it does not have anything, you are getting the null pointer exception.

Also, I think if you call this :

`getid` first and then calling like this :

```
String confirmationURL = "https://test-webapp.net/#/type=confirm";
List<String> newurls = new ArrayList<String>();
getid(driver);
newurls.add(confirmationURL + "&id=" + createdValue.get("latestDataId"));
```

should help you by past this issue.

Comment: -i tried to give as you said but when i run the entire script it causes stale element it is bz the method has lastetid.click and also createdValue.get("latestDataId")); i would need both of these lines bz in one screen iam clicking the id and in another screen iam appending the id to the url can i get a input on what i need to do to have both in one method and use the same method in all the places

Comment: This ticket is solely for null pointer exception, which was resolved. I don't see a point for unacceptance. As I am aware you already have a new ticket created for stale element reference, right ? We don't encourage folks to unaccept the already accepted ticket, if it solved their query. Also you should ask one question per post.